# $a^x = a e^x $. What is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the following function:

$f(x) = a^x$

Now I take the logarithm of both sides:

$\ln(f(x)) = \ln(a^x) = x\ln(a)$

After that, I exponentiate both sides:

$e^{\ln(f(x))} = e^{\ln(a)} e^{x} \implies f(x) = a  e^x = a^x$

Obviously, this is wrong, but I can't spot my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've mistaken $e^{\ln(a)\times x}$ for $e^{\ln a}\times e^x$. Remember that $e^u\times e^v$ is $e^{u+v}$, whereas $(e^u)^v=e^{uv}$.

Answer (score 4):

$e^{x\ln(a)} \ne e^x\cdot e^{\ln a} = e^{x+\ln a}$